Rviz2 not able to create the rendering window Ubuntu 24
ve been trying to launch RVIZ2 but always I get the following error log:
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread [INFO] [1722218336.755525763] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED [INFO] [1722218336.755651675] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.5 (GLSL 4.5) [ERROR] [1722218336.772153908] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: RenderingAPIException: Invalid parentWindowHandle (wrong server or screen) in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre_vendor-prefix/src/ogre_vendor/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 246) [ERROR] [1722218336.772298763] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: RenderingAPIException: Invalid parentWindowHandle (wrong server or screen) in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre_vendor-prefix/src/ogre_vendor/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/ [ERROR] [1722218336.773535267] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: RenderingAPIException: Invalid parentWindowHandle (wrong server or screen) in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre_vendor-prefix/src/ogre_vendor/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 246) [ERROR] [1722218336.773580461] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: RenderingAPIException: Invalid parentWindowHandle (wrong server or screen) in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre_vendor-prefix/src/ogre_vendor/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 246) [ERROR] [1722218336.776422552] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: RenderingAPIException: Invalid parentWindowHandle (wrong server or screen) in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre_vendor-prefix/src/ogre_vendor/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 246) [ERROR] [1722218336.776433805] [rviz2]: Unable to create the rendering window after 100 tries terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error' what(): Unable to create the rendering window after 100 tries Aborted (core dumped)
I run the glxgears and it runs at 60Hz as my monitor, I tried run rviz with software rendering with LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 and didn't work Also I uninstall and install rviz
I used to be able to run rviz with ros foxxy and Noetic without problems
Do somebody knows what could I do to fix this?
I am using a laptop HP Zbook 15 G2 with an Intel Core i7-4810MQ 16GB
